# How to sort Mongodb query for a nested structure

Tags: mongodb, sorting, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have a wall and several comments related to a wall,

```
{
    "Wall_id": "wall002",
    "user_id": "user002",
    "message_author": "AuthorB",
    "wall_message": "content:TRY",
    "posted_on": "24/8/15",
    "author_id": "A002",
    "path_to_files": ["home/path"],
    "wall_recepients":["user002","user003","user004","user005","user006"],
    "w_timestamp": 678,
    "Comments": [
        {
            "comment_id": "cmt001",
            "Wall_id": "wall001",
            "user_id": "user001",
            "pathtofile": "[home/doc/file]",
            "comment": "try 2",
            "profile_pic": "home2/pic.jpg",
            "user_name": "user2",
            "c_timestamp": 700
       },
        {
            "comment_id": "cmt001",
            "Wall_id": "wall001",
            "user_id": "user001",
            "pathtofile": "[home/doc/file]",
            "comment": "try 2",
            "profile_pic": "home2/pic.jpg",
            "user_name": "user2",
            "c_timestamp": 1000
       }
    ]
}
```

I want a query that sorts wall elements sorted based on w_timestamp and comments array for each wall sorted based on c_timestamp.

I am using pymongo and tried ,

```
searchUser = "user002"
result = post.find({"wall_recepients":{"$in":[searchUser]}}).sort([["post.w_timestamp",DESCENDING],["post.Comments.c_timestamp",DESCENDING]])
```

DESCENDING is pymongo.DESCENDING

Thanks in advance!
Expected output :

Given a user id , fetch all wall items where wall_recepients contains the user_id,like,

```
[

{
    "Wall_id": "wall002",
    "user_id": "user002",
    "message_author": "AuthorB",
    "wall_message": "content:TRY",
    "posted_on": "24/8/15",
    "author_id": "A002",
    "path_to_files": ["home/path"],
    "wall_recepients":["user002","user003","user004","user005","user006"],
    "w_timestamp": 678,
    "Comments": [
        {
            "comment_id": "cmt001",
            "Wall_id": "wall001",
            "user_id": "user001",
            "pathtofile": "[home/doc/file]",
            "comment": "try 2",
            "profile_pic": "home2/pic.jpg",
            "user_name": "user2",
            "c_timestamp": 700
       },
        {
            "comment_id": "cmt001",
            "Wall_id": "wall001",
            "user_id": "user001",
            "pathtofile": "[home/doc/file]",
            "comment": "try 2",
            "profile_pic": "home2/pic.jpg",
            "user_name": "user2",
            "c_timestamp": 1000
       }
    ]
},

{
    "Wall_id": "wall001",
    "user_id": "user002",
    "message_author": "AuthorB",
    "wall_message": "content:TRY",
    "posted_on": "24/8/15",
    "author_id": "A002",
    "path_to_files": ["home/path"],
    "wall_recepients":["user002","user003","user004","user005","user006"],
    "w_timestamp": 666,
    "Comments": [
        {
            "comment_id": "cmt001",
            "Wall_id": "wall001",
            "user_id": "user001",
            "pathtofile": "[home/doc/file]",
            "comment": "try 2",
            "profile_pic": "home2/pic.jpg",
            "user_name": "user2",
            "c_timestamp": 124
       },
        {
            "comment_id": "cmt001",
            "Wall_id": "wall001",
            "user_id": "user001",
            "pathtofile": "[home/doc/file]",
            "comment": "try 2",
            "profile_pic": "home2/pic.jpg",
            "user_name": "user2",
            "c_timestamp": 246
       }
    ]
}


]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I just want every wall id to be sorted by timestamp in descending order and within each , I also expect the comments to be sorted by timestamp (either ASC or DESC)

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35405835/edit) link on your question to add the expected result

Comment: Thanks, I have added the expected output , does that help ?

Comment: What do you mean by *sorted by comments*? Do you want to sort the `Comments` array? If yes why do you need that?

Comment: I thought that would make sense when showing in the UI, most recent wall elements and for each wall I need comments in a sorted manner